# Filter a most recent 2 logs in comparison with a given time from a log file in Shell scripting (.ksh)

Tags: shell, unix, grep, ksh, unix-timestamp

I am analyzing a large log file of a socket server to track some events. I have problem with getting most recent 2 message logs for a given time (one is before and another is after the given time) using a shell script. in this case only thing I can use is date-time value of the log file

```
 e.g. triggering time: 2013-10-31 07:29:45.311
    think I have an event from another log at 2013-10-31 07:29:45.311 and need to filter 
the most recent message log one is before above time and other one is after from below sample log. 

    given time = 2013-10-31 07:29:45.311
    then triggered times for most recent log messages should be 
    1) before the given time: message at 2013-10-31 07:29:34.415
    2) after the given time: message at 2013-10-31 07:30:34.473
```

is this possible to do using a shell script ?

```
Sample log:

    2013-10-31 07:23:33.931 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:24:35.273 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:25:33.973 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:26:34.111 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:27:34.151 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:28:34.273 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:29:34.415 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:30:34.473 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:31:34.595 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:32:34.616 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
    2013-10-31 07:33:35.673 INFO  - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
```

Comment: Someone down voted this question, please explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its some complicated to do, but can be done by convert date to epoch time.

```
value="2013-10-31 07:29:45.311"
awk '
    {
    split($1,a,"-")
    split($2,b,"[:.]")
    t1=mktime(a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3] " " b[1] " " b[2] " " b[3]) "." b[4]
    split(v,c,"[- :.]")
    t2=mktime(c[1] " " c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4] " " c[5] " " c[6]) "." c[7]   
    }
    t1>t2 {print  l "\n" $0;exit}
    {l=$0}
    ' v="$value" logfile

2013-10-31 07:29:34.415 INFO - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
2013-10-31 07:30:34.473 INFO - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
```

---

Save it to an variable

```
res=$(awk '
    {
    split($1,a,"-")
    split($2,b,"[:.]")
    t1=mktime(a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3] " " b[1] " " b[2] " " b[3]) "." b[4]
    split(v,c,"[- :.]")
    t2=mktime(c[1] " " c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4] " " c[5] " " c[6]) "." c[7]   
    }
    t1>t2 {print  l "\n" $0;exit}
    {l=$0}
    ' v="$value" logfile)

echo "$res"
2013-10-31 07:29:34.415 INFO - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
2013-10-31 07:30:34.473 INFO - TTT153|Receive|0000131|....
```

Comment: I have not use 'awk' before, I cannot form this script portion within my script. Is this just follow like this 
`awk '{above entire code lines}' v="$value" file `
here, "file" should represent to pass the log file name. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes `file` is the `logfile` I have updated the post to show how to store this to a variable.

Comment: is this because of #!/bin/ksh ? (reason for `awk: Function mktime is not defined`.)

Comment: I think my system doesn't support mktime() (I am working on a HP-Nonstop server and I cannot install programs, is there any other options to use)

Comment: If you have the `date` command, you can use it to convert to and from epoch time and then compare value.

Comment: mktime is working, but the time comparison is not working. So result is an empty string. (just exit from the program), If change the comparison to "<" then this print the very first message.
Still I couldn't figure out this.

Comment: corrected, There was a problem when doing split the text from file. Now working as expected. Thanks.